# sql: combine two tables around timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have two tables with sensor data and I want to combine both tables into one.

Table 1:

```
Sensor1 | Timestamp
34        2018-22-05 23:23:34
25        2018-22-05 22:23:23
51        2019-22-05 12:34:56
```

Table 2:

```
Sensor2 | Timestamp
27        2018-22-05 23:37:33
29        2018-22-05 22:36:47
66        2019-22-05 12:34:56
```

And my desired result is:

Expected Table:

```
Sensor1 | Sensor2 | Timestamp
          27        2018-22-05 23:37:33
34                  2018-22-05 23:23:34
          29        2018-22-05 22:36:47
25                  2018-22-05 22:23:23
51        66        2019-22-05 12:34:56
```

It is very unlikely that we could have the same timestamp in both tables, but even if we do, it shouldn't be a problem to have values in both Sensor colums.

I have tried with UNION, UNION ALL, OUTER JOIN, but I always end up with two timestamp columns.

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks and best regards,
Rodrigo.

Comment: Put your sensor data in 1 table and add a column indicating the ID of the sensor. Problem solved. This is not going to be maintainable when you have 50, 100, 10,000 sensors and have to maintain a table for each.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all your comments. Indeed I am trying to combine these two tables in AWS Athena, which is Presto, and I am not able to replicate your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

just use `UNION ALL` to combine two tables.

- `Table1` set `Sensor2` column be `NULL`
- `Table2` set `Sensor1` column be `NULL`

then order by `Timestamp`

```
SELECT * FROM (
select Sensor1 'Sensor1',null 'Sensor2',Ti from T 
UNION ALL 
select null 'Sensor1', Sensor1 'Sensor2',Ti from T2 
) t
order by ti desc
```

*sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb22b/9*

**OUTPUT**

```
| Sensor1 | Sensor2 |                   Ti |
|---------|---------|----------------------|
|  (null) |      27 | 2018-05-22T23:37:33Z |
|      34 |  (null) | 2018-05-22T23:23:34Z |
|  (null) |      29 | 2018-05-22T22:36:47Z |
|      25 |  (null) | 2018-05-22T22:23:23Z |
```

if you want to let `NULL` be empty string. you can use `coalesce` function.

```
SELECT coalesce(Sensor1,'') as 'Sensor1',
       coalesce(Sensor2,'') as 'Sensor2',
       ti
FROM (
select Sensor1 'Sensor1',null 'Sensor2',Ti from T 
UNION ALL 
select null 'Sensor1', Sensor1 'Sensor2',Ti from T2 
) t
order by ti desc
```

Comment: This solution does not take into account the 51/66 row. It produces two separate rows instead of a single "merged" one.

Comment: This is the solution I used and I works. Also in AWS Athena!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheImpaler for the single "merged" one check the answer from Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

If no duplicates appear within a table and you want to combine results from both tables, I would suggest aggregation:

```
select max(sensor1) as sensor1, max(sensor2) as sensor2, timestamp
from ((select Sensor1, null as Sensor2, timestamp from t1
      ) union all
      (select null, Sensor2, timestamp
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by timetamp
order by timestamp desc;
```

Comment: This worked as expected which combines/de-duplicates results due to `group by` clause (which is not present in other answers at this time)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
  select sensor1, null as sensor2, timestamp from table1
    where timestamp not in (select timestamp from table2)
  union all
  select null, sensor2, timestamp from table2
    where timestamp not in (select timestamp from table1)
  union all
  select t1.sensor1, t2.sensor2, t1.timestamp from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
  ) a
order by timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what flavour of SQL you're using the simplest way of doing this might be to use a [FULL OUTER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp), something like this;

```
select
    t1.Sensor1,
    t2.Sensor2,
    coalesce(t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp) as Timestamp
from 
    table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2 on t2.Timestamp = t1.Timestamp
```